# How to Table sorter in node page?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a table in node page. i have requirement to make it sort-able on click.

can anyone help?

Comment: i tried `view Tablesorter`. but it is for D6 and only for views.

Comment: You have a nice example that extends a query with tablesort at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!tablesort.inc/class/TableSort/7 I have used something similar and it works great.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try out these:

- [Tablesorter](http://drupal.org/project/tablesorter)
- [Tsort](http://drupal.org/project/tsort)
- [DataTables](http://drupal.org/project/datatables)
- [FooTable](http://drupal.org/project/footable)

Answer (score 1):

I used something like this in one of my installations:

```
// create a table of nodes of a specific content type
function MYMODULE_create_table($node_type) {
  // setup headers
  $headers = array(
     array('data' => 'Nid'),
     array('data' => 'Title', 'field' => 'title'),
     array('data' => 'Status')
  );
  // build query
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')->extend('PagerDefault');
  $query->limit(30);
  $query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'status'));
  $query->condition('n.type', $node_type, '=');
  // make it sortable
  $query = $query->extend('TableSort')->orderByHeader($headers);
  // execute query
  $result = $query->execute();
  $rows = array();
  foreach($result as $node) {
    $rows[] = array(
       $node->nid,
       $node->title,
       $node->status
    );
  }
  // add a pager if needed
  if(count($rows) && ($pager = theme('pager'))) {
    $rows[] = array(
      array(
    'data' => $pager,
    'colspan' => 3,
  )
    );
  }
  // return html for table
  return theme('table',
            array(
                'header' => $headers,
                'rows'=>$rows,
                'empty' => 'No products found...',
            )
    );
}
```

The above perhaps work just as is, but it might give you some clue on how this can be done.

[TableSort](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!tablesort.inc/class/TableSort/7)

Comment: i have a table simply created with CKEditor. how this code will work?

Comment: You should haved specified that in your question, hard to me to just know that.